# Code Coverage for Typescript using karma-jasmine and istanbul

Tags: typescript, istanbul, karma-coverage

I am trying to get the Code Coverage for my typescript Code in karma framework using Istanbul
in karma.conf typescript files are included and by karma typescript-preprocessor we  able to do unit testing and code coverage of the typescript code but Code coverage report come for trans piled JavaScript code

**How can I get the coverage report for typescript code?**

Here is my `karma.conf` file.

```js
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    preprocessors: {
        'src/**/*.ts': ['typescript', 'coverage'],
        'test/**/*.ts': ['typescript']
    },
    typescriptPreprocessor: {
        options: {
            sourceMap: false, // (optional) Generates corresponding .map file.
            target: 'ES5', // (optional) Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), or 'ES5'
            module: 'amd', // (optional) Specify module code generation: 'commonjs' or 'amd'
            noImplicitAny: true, // (optional) Warn on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type.
            noResolve: false, // (optional) Skip resolution and preprocessing.
            removeComments: true, // (optional) Do not emit comments to output.
            concatenateOutput: false // (optional) Concatenate and emit output to single file. By default true if module option is omited, otherwise false.
        },
        // extra typing definitions to pass to the compiler (globs allowed)
        // transforming the filenames
        transformPath: function (path) {
            return path.replace(/\.ts$/, '.js');
        }

        //options: {
        //    sourceMap: true,
        //}
    },

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [

      'src/**/*.ts',
      'test/**/*.ts'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
      
    ],
    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress', 'junit', 'growl', 'coverage'
    reporters: ['progress','coverage'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // Start these browsers, currently available:
    // - Chrome
    // - ChromeCanary
    // - Firefox
    // - Opera (has to be installed with `npm install karma-opera-launcher`)
    // - Safari (only Mac; has to be installed with `npm install karma-safari-launcher`)
    // - PhantomJS
    // - IE (only Windows; has to be installed with `npm install karma-ie-launcher`)
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],


    // If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
    captureTimeout: 60000,


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false,
    plugins: [
  'karma-jasmine',
  'karma-chrome-launcher',
  'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
  'karma-typescript-preprocessor',
  'karma-coverage'
  //require('../../../node_modules/karma-typescript-preprocessor/index.js')
    ]

  });
};
```

Comment: You can use remap-istanbul for that: https://github.com/SitePen/remap-istanbul

Comment: I have not found a good example of using remap-istanbul with TypeScript.

Answer (score 14):

Install [`karma-typescript`](https://github.com/monounity/karma-typescript):

```
npm install karma-typescript --save-dev
```

Put this in your karma.conf.js:

```
frameworks: ["jasmine", "karma-typescript"],

files: [
    { pattern: "src/**/*.ts" }
],

preprocessors: {
    "**/*.ts": ["karma-typescript"]
},

reporters: ["progress", "karma-typescript"],

browsers: ["Chrome"]
```

This will run your Typescript unit tests on the fly and generate Istanbul html coverage that look like this:

[image]

To run the above example you need to install a few packages:

`npm install @types/jasmine jasmine-core karma karma-chrome-launcher karma-cli karma-jasmine karma-typescript typescript`

This is the complete configuration for unit testing vanilla Typescript code, no `tsconfig.json` needed in this case. For more complex setups with Angular, React etc you can find examples in the [`examples folder`](https://github.com/monounity/karma-typescript/tree/master/examples) and in the [`integration tests`](https://github.com/monounity/karma-typescript/tree/master/tests/integration-latest).

Answer (score 1):

We are using instanbul-remap for our project and it works quite nicely. To create our coverage reports, we run the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

PROJECT_PATH="$(dirname $0)/../"

cd $PROJECT_PATH
echo Creating coverage reports for `pwd`

if [ ! -d "target/dist" ]; then
  echo
  echo "target/dist directory not found. Must compile source with \`npm install\` before running tests."
  echo
  exit 1;
fi

COVERAGE_DIR=target/coverage-raw
REMAP_DIR=target/coverage-ts

mkdir -p $COVERAGE_DIR
mkdir -p $REMAP_DIR

# run coverage on unit tests only
echo Creating coverage reports for unit tests
node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover --dir $COVERAGE_DIR nodeunit `find target/dist/test/ -name *.test.js` > /dev/null

# re-map the coverage report so that typescript sources are shown
echo Remapping coverage reports for typescript
node_modules/.bin/remap-istanbul -i $COVERAGE_DIR/coverage.json -o $REMAP_DIR -t html

echo Coverage report located at $REMAP_DIR/index.html
```

Our project uses nodeunit as a test harness as it is a node application. However, I would expect that a similar approach would work for karma.

Comment: Works perfectly for `mocha` run tests as well

Answer (score 1):

There is [`karma-remap-istanbul`](https://github.com/marcules/karma-remap-istanbul) which integrates nicely [`remap-istanbul`](https://github.com/SitePen/remap-istanbul) with karma. Documentation is pretty self explanatory but one thing - to have summary on the console the config is `text: undefined` (otherwise text output goes to the file).

So it is possible to have coverage summary directly from karma however when `ts` sources are not available in the same directory as `karma.config.js` `karma-remap-istanbul` still needs some more development regarding configuration to be able to generate full html reports.